# Angular Router URL Encoding Special Characters and Browser Behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I just can't figure out the solution for such problem. I'm designing search engine and I'd like to display in url what user is trying to find  like this:

```
https://my-site.com/search;query=%28rockstar;search=true;page=0
```

User is trying to find `(rockstar` phrase.

When I paste this url to the browser it works as expected but the Chrome browser is displaying this url like this:

```
https://my-site.com/search;query=(rockstar;search=true;page=0
```

So the `%28` is changed to `(`. I don't know if this behavior is Angular or Browser dependent. When I have url with `(` then refreshing `F5` is not working because Angular Router is reporting problem like this:

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rockstar;search=true;page=0'
```

Copying link from url address bar is also useless because of this behavior the copied link contains `(` character (not `%28`). How to prevent `%28` and other special characters to be not decoded by Browser in url address bar? The problem arises in Angular v5.2.5

Here is the demo with this problem: https://angular-url-problem.stackblitz.io

Notice that in Angular 6 the problem doesn't exists: https://angular-url-problem-v6.stackblitz.io

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz with the minimum code to reproduce the issue please?

Comment: If nobody will know answer for this then I will try to provide it.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta [ask] specifies otherwise : `Help others reproduce the problem`. Please provide a [mcve] so we can test it without having to implement it ourselves (and I insist on the `Verifiable`, meaning you must reproduce the issue, not just provide a stackblitz)

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not able to reproduce your issue. If i load https://angular-hzu1wi.stackblitz.io/?query=%28rockstar;search=true;page=0 it works fine.

Comment: You can't reproduce because You are using query parameters after `?` character.

Comment: Alright, https://angular-hzu1wi.stackblitz.io/search;query=%28rockstar;search=true;page=0 then. Bear in mind that calling `encodeURIComponent('(')` just returns a `(` anyway

Comment: Here is the demo: https://angular-url-problem.stackblitz.io/search

Comment: @trichetriche - the demo is here for Angular 5: https://angular-url-problem.stackblitz.io and for Angular 6: https://angular-url-problem-v6.stackblitz.io

Comment: Usually one needs to post the link to the code, not to the demo ... But I know how to get to it. I'm looking at it.

Comment: @trichetriche Sorry for that. Here are the links to the code v5: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem and v6: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem-v6 The code is the same. Just the dependencies are changed.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta i am getting the same prob. did u solved this?

Comment: In some way yes. I decided to rewrite application and not use route specific parameters but rather use queryParams

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're not looking at the right params. In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem-v6-h6nlh5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.ts), as you can see, you don't even need to encode your parameters.

You also don't need to go too far to create query params. Angular provides a high level of abstraction, use it to your advantage.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._route.queryParamMap
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.form.patchValue({
        query: params.get('query') || '',
      });
    });
}

public onSubmit(): void {
  const query: string = this.form.value.query;
  this._router.navigate(['/search'], {
    queryParams: {
      query
    }
  })
}
```

**EDIT** with matrix notation : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem-v6-o3vskb?file=src/app/search/search.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.form.patchValue({
        query: params['query'] || '',
      });
    });
}

public onSubmit(): void {
  const query: string = this.form.value.query;
  this._router.navigate(['/search', { query }]);
}
```

Comment: But this is not what I'm expecting. You provide me an solution that adds query parameters (after `?` character). This is totally different solution.

Comment: [With matrix notation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem-v6-o3vskb?file=src/app/search/search.component.ts) if you want. My points still stand.

Comment: This is Angular 6 solution and I need Angular 5 solution. I wrote that everything works in Angular 6. Take a look at the question description because I updated it.

Comment: Then it is an issue and you need to upgrade to Angular 6 (sorry, didn't read your question again, my bad).

Comment: Currently I can't update to Angular 6 and that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Then currently you can't use matrix notation ... Consider switching to query params, [which work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-problem-abfsgs?file=src/app/search/search.component.ts), or try migrating to 6th version.

Comment: Thanks. I will experiment with `router.urlSerializer.serialize` and `parse` methods and I will look for differences in implementation between v5 and v6 angular on github and I will provide my own solution. Can't change url's because we need to have backward compatibility with routes :)

Comment: Maybe you could directly change the location with `window.location.href` too, and append the parameters yourself. The drawback is that the application will be reloaded, but that's still one solution among others ...

Comment: @trichetriche i am using Angular 6 and i am getting this error. so upgrading doesn't solve. This roblem happens when url is something like this http://localhost:8080/tags/raspberry(cake)

Comment: @Rafique just because you use Angular 6 doesn't mean it should work on the spot. You could have done something wrong and not realize it. Feel free to make a question with your issue and a [mcve].