# Redirecting to a url with queryParams

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect, routes

I'm creating a redirect in angular 6

The redirect itself is very simple it works like this

**get destination url from params**:

```
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['route'] || '/';
```

**Redirect**

```
if (this.returnUrl) {
  this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

The problem I have in when the url has parameters in it, for example:

**Redirect URL** is

`'/survey/finish?key=7krmpqpC0P&mind=Akkoord&companyNumber=%5B%5BQ2%5D'`

As a result I get the **error**

`Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'survey/finish%3Fkey%3D7krmpqpC0P&mind%3DAkkoord&companyNumber%3D%255B%255BQ2%255D'`

How can I correctly redirect to the given **string**?

So `http://localhost:4200/survey/finish?key=7krmpqpC0P&mind=Akkoord&companyNumber=%5B%5BQ2%5D`

My route looks like thid

```
  {
    path: 'survey/finish',
    component: CallbackComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
```

Comment: I marked it as [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094849/angular-router-url-encoding-special-characters-and-browser-behavior/52098201#comment91148138_52098201) because the issue is the same, and you might find a solution in the original question. If you think this doesn't fit your case, please let me know and explain why.

Comment: what do your routes look like?

Comment: There seems to be a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843291/10696285) that worked for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use **navigateByUrl** method:

```
if (this.returnUrl) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
} else {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution - I wonder why this thread is way underrated ;)